How can I change the length of hair along with the size of my character?
It's my first time using Blender, and I decided to create a character. However, I am not familiar with all the tools and basics, so I made a mistake by not considering the size of my character. As a result, the character turned out to be much larger thanintended. Now, I would like to fix this mistake, but when Itry to reduce the size of the character, the size of the hair remains the same. photo. Is it possible to reduce both the character and the hair simultaneously, orwill I need to start over and redo the character from scratch? Anysuggestions or advicewould be greatly appreciated.

Is your hair a particle system/GN setup? If so you'll just need to go into the settings there and scale your hair length value by the same amount. Like if you scaled by .5 then you can literally just type " * .5" after the value in the field and it will do the math for you.
